# How to push data to same array in java script in several time in same function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I'm getting values from database in json structure. and i want to display them in table in javascript.Data come in following format.

```
"free_issue": [
{
  "product_id": [14, 15, 16],
  "free_product_ids": [15],
  "structure": [
    {
      "req_qty": 10,
      "free_qty": 2
    },
    {
      "req_qty": 20,
      "free_qty": 5
    },
    {
      "req_qty": 50,
      "free_qty": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

From those data i want to push this data to table row. data in same row with 4 columns.I used array push method to push data. but i'm unable to get it in correct way.
[image: Out put table]

in here all the data should in one row.

Please help me to do this.......

Comment: I find hard to understand you, could you elaborate your desired output, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

have You tried to do like this?

```
"free_issue": [
{
  "product_id": [14, 15, 16],
  "free_product_ids": [null, 15, null],
  "structure": [
    {
      "req_qty": 10,
      "free_qty": 2
    },
    {
      "req_qty": 20,
      "free_qty": 5
    },
    {
      "req_qty": 50,
      "free_qty": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I mean You've to generate these arrays before and then attach these arrays to fields of object. Notice: all of arrays must be same length to be able aligned to correct rows.